# Is there a way to verify whether the apk file is generated from the given source code or not?

Tags: java, android, apk

I am a member of administration team for a Govt organization, where the client submit their app and it's source code for approval process. I am looking for a solution to verify whether the given apk file is generated from the given source code or not. This application is distributed outside the Google Play, so we want to make sure that the client is distributing only the app which is approved by the admin team.

Please suggest a method.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "reproducible build". There has been some work in this area (see [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/docs/Reproducible_Builds/), for example), but I am not aware of a general-purpose solution.

Comment: You could decompile the apk I guess, but if the code is obfuscated it might be harder to compare to the real code.

Comment: You can decompile the source code from the apk and compare the code.

Comment: @HristoStoyanov i thought about this, but the code is obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

You already receive the sources, so the easiest next step is to get everything being needed for the creation of the APK and do that yourself from the sources the vendor provides.

Decompiling the classes in the APK and comparing that to the given source is in my eyes a wrong way. First, you might want to prevent exactly that to happen when the application is "out there", so the APK might contain obfuscated classes, also the decompiled source can look completely different after the compiler did some optimizations. And I'm not alone with this point of view. Have a look at the discussions about voting computers and the difficulty to verify that the computer isn't unaltered and runs with the source the vendor provided for the audits, etc.

Answer (score -2):

When building the release version of your app, you **should sign it with a secure, unique signing key**. This way when the user installs the apk, they will be able to install it "over" the previous version and know this is the same app.

The best approach would probably be to accept just the code from the client, review it and then **build and sign the app yourself**. This way you can be sure what goes into the apk and lock that in place with the signature.

Comment: "I am looking for a solution to verify whether the given apk file is generated from the given source code or not"

Comment: "client submit their app and it's source code for approval process"